# Display keys and values with Angular array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array in Angular like this:

```
$scope.test = [
  {'item1' : 'answer1' },
  {'item2' : 'answer2' },
  {'item3' : 'answer3' }
];
```

And so on...

Now there's 2 things I want to do. Firstly I want to use an ng-repeat to iterate through the array and display the keys and values separately. I tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in test">
  {{key}} = {{value}}
</div>
```

But that produces results like this:

```
0  = {"item1" : "answer1"}
1  = {"item2" : "answer2"}
2  = {"item3" : "answer3"}
```

Whereas I want it to display like this:

```
item1  = answer1
item2  = answer2
item3  = answer3
```

The second thing I'd like to do is use the keys to display results from a different array. For example I have this array:

```
$scope.item1.question = 'some question';
```

So as I'm going through the ng-repeat I'd like to do something like this:

```
{{key}}.question
```

to display the string `'some question'`.

But this doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Use nested `ng-repeat`s.

The `ng-repeat` is only looping over the array and so its writing out the element's index as the key. You need to nest another ng-repeat to iterate over the contained objects:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in test">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj">
        {{key}} = {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

### 2. Use square brackets notation and an object wrapper.

To access an object using dynamic key that comes from another object inside `ng-repeat`, use array notation that allows expressions:

```
$scope.model = {
    item1: {
        question : 'some question 1'
    },
    item2: {
        question : 'some question 2'
    },
    item3: {
        question : 'some question 3'
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    {{ model[key].question }}
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf2B6/)**

Comment: Ah nested `ng-repeats`! I didn't know you could do that. Thanks, but is there a way now to use the key to call the extra array? like `{{key}}.question` but where the `{{key}}` is treated as a string so it's the same as calling `item.question` for example.